# How do I run Python 2 and 3 at the same time on a Mac?

Tags: python

As I understand it, MacOS comes with Python 2.7 by default. I run Home Assistant on using Python 3.5 and it works great. There is a HA component that requires Python 2 but not sure how to specify it to run on the Python 2 installation.

I’ve asked this question on the Home Assistant forums and didn’t receive a response since most seem like they are using a Pi with Linux and the FireTV component. Here’s the instructions but looking for help to run the script as Python 2

https://home-assistant.io/components/media_player.firetv/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it like you want certain component of your application to be running on python 2 or the whole applications

Comment: Can you run `python2 --version` and/or `python3 --version` from your mac's terminal? If yes, can you run `python2 /path/to/script.py` and accomplish what you are looking for?

Comment: I have installed python2 and python3. I can also create virtualenv for python3 or python2 using `virtualenv -p python3 myenv` choose the version you want. To run python3 use `python3 scriptname.py` . for python2 just use python